# Different type of import in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

**In React Native We have to import packages in following methods .**

1. import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
2. import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

what is the different between these import statements ?

Comment: Here it explain well. Worth reading. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import  and also here http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Comment: Thanks  @cjmling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you export your components/things like this

```
export class Foo extends Component {…
```

you have to import it like this

```
import {Foo} from './foo.js'
```

When you export as default, like here

```
export default class Bar extends Component {…
```

you can import it like this

```
import Bar from './bar.js'
```

You may, of course, have only one default export per file.

Comment: Thanks @Viktor Sec

Comment: So that's mean in this example `import Foo, { getBar } from 'react-native-xxx';` the file got 2 export class?

Comment: Yes, `Foo` is the default export, while `getBar` is just a regular one.

Answer (score 1):

### Default Export

The default export is done as follows:

```
const student={
  name: 'Sam'
}
export default student;
```

and it is imported as

```
import student from './student.js'
```

or

```
import std from './student.js'
```

The name in the receiving file is up to you. There can be only one default export.

### Named Export

The named export is done as follows:

```
export const anyFunc = () => {...}
```

or

```
export const anyValue = 10;
```

and it is imported as:

```
import { anyFunction } from './anyfile.js'
import { anyValue } from './anyfile.js'
```

One can have multiple named exports per file.
Import the specific exports you want and surround them in braces.
The name of the imported module has to be the same as the name of the exported module.